# How to remove margin around cards in android prelollipop?

Tags: android

Everything is fine in Android Lollipop, but there is extra space around card view in Android 4.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_member"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
```

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fcxk.png)

Comment: No you cant period. Well there is one way which is to create your own card in 9patch with your designated margin/padding on it.

Comment: Can you post your `CardView`'s `xml`?